# How do i reclaim OWNERSHIP of an ENS domain

Tags: ether, ens

new ENS user here.  I have one problem and one question.

Problem:
I transferred ownership of my ENS domain to a CROWDSALE contract address, by using setOwner().  The goal was to use "myname-eth" to resolve to the crowdsale address.  However, that didn't work.  The old address of which the original ENS domain was bought still resolved to "myname-eth".  So my question is....  how can I change ownership back to the original address?  When I try to do that with myetherwallet, it says "bad jump instruction" and fails.

Question:  How can I change the address which "myname-eth" resolves to?  I want to change that address to a crowdsale address.  So currently it points to 0x12345.  I want to change it to 0x55555, for example.

I'm currently stuck and have scourged the net to find answers but nothing that has helped so far.

Answer (score 1):

When working with a `.eth` name, it's important to understand the difference between:

1. Transferring a deed
2. Transferring name ownership

[These docs](https://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/userguide.html#managing-ownership) are worth a deep read through. The gist:

Transferring a deed is irrevocable. The only way to get ownership back is to get the current deed owner to send it back to you.

If you transferred the name, but still own the deed, you can reclaim it by calling `finalizeAuction()`.

Comment: I did setOwner() to a crowdsale address.  The deed is still owned by the original wallet address but the owner is the crowdsale address.  What can I do to reset the owner to the original wallet address (deed address)

Comment: You can reclaim it by calling `finalizeAuction()` from the address that owns the deed.